# Getting null pointer exception from setSelected()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm trying to implement marquee textview in a fragment at the runtime.

**Problem #1:** I get a null pointer exception at `tv.setSelected(true);` on the first fragment.
Everything works ok until I put the marquee code for the text view.

**Problem #2:**  How can I move to a new fragment instead of a new intent in the list view for `public void onItemClick` ?

This is my code:

```
 public static class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

 ArrayList< String > ar;
 ArrayAdapter< String >  ad ;
 ListView lv ;
 TextView     tv;

public FragmentOne() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle        
         savedInstanceState) {
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, container, false);
          tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);  

        tv.setSelected(true);
     ar = new ArrayList<String>(); 
     lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1); 
     for (int i = 0 ; i< 10  ; i++){

        ar.add("My Item " + String.valueOf(i)); 

      }
      ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>
     (getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, 
             ar);

     lv.setAdapter(ad);
     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                          Toast t = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Message",
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                          t.show();

                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), tst.class); 


                        startActivity(i); 

            }
        }); 


    return rootView;
}
```

}

this is the xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mywidget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="94dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:lines="2"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text="صور أندلسية ..... صفحة الأندلس ....معارك  أندلسية ..... الأندلس في سطور    
     ..... الأندلس :  "
    android:textColor="#ff4500"
    android:focusable="false" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @sunil not needed, because he marked: "i have a null pointer exception at tv.setSelected(true);"

Comment: you aren't using properly the View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, container, false);
          tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); And for that reason the tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); return null

Comment: post your full XML, you are using some ids in the code that are not in the XML

Comment: check the id of textview in xml should be same

Comment: Why not use just `tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);` ?

Comment: check if you have `textview` with id `textView1` in layout one

Comment: @matheszabi really i don't unserstad the idea thast you are try to tell ..can youput some details please

Comment: you have a textview id `android:id="@+id/mywidget"` so it should be `tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mywidget)`

Comment: @g00dy it's causes an error

Comment: @aromaKhan it causes an error because the textView1 doesn't exist

Comment: @Raghunandan hhhhhh ok yeah how i missed it ,thanks alot ,, what about the second problem that i have

Comment: @aromaKhan You should really have two separate Stack Overflow *questions* instead of posting both on a single post.

Comment: @BLaZuRE yeah i know and i do this from mins ago

Answer (score 3):

> Null pointer Exceptions usually happens when you didn't initialized
>   the object Or initialized to null.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your 1st issue here - I strongly suggest posting 2 separate questions.

If the NPE is thrown at:

```
tv.setSelected(true);
```

(would need a LogCat to make sure)

... then your `TextView` is `null`.

In turn, this means that `rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);` did not return a valid `TextView`, likely because no child with such id (or of that type) was found in your `R.layout.one` xml.

Make sure your `R.layout.one` xml contains a `TextView` node with id `textView1`.

**Edit**

If the layout you posted correponds to `R.layout.one`, it's pretty trivial: the `TextView` 's id there is `mywidget`.

You'll need to change that.

Also make sure that layout is not used somewhere else, otherwise changing the id in the layout might pose problems.

You may want to change the id reference in your `Fragment` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you don't have any TextView with the id `textView1` in your XML.

**EDIT**

You will also have problem with the ListView, once you need a ListView in your XML with the id `listView1`